# Multinomial theorem: find the coefficient of $x^3 y^4$ in $(x+2y+3)^{10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients

I have trouble solving this problem:

> Find the coefficient of $x^3y^4$  in  $(x+2y+3)^{10}$

The reason for that I struggle with this problem, is because it has an higher order (10) the $x^3y^4$.

In the solution, he has made this $(x+2y+3)^{10}$ to this -> $(7x+2y)^7$. But I don't understand how he did that?

Comment: Try to at least state the problem correcly. Even though I know what you want.

Comment: The terms of the development will be of the form $x^i(2y)^j3^k10!/(i!j!k!)$, with $i+j+k=10$. Find $i,j,k$.

Comment: So basically, I already have $x^3$ and $y^4$, so then I have i=3 and j=4, right ? So the remaining value should be k=3, am i right ?

Comment: In the end, should we get something like this -> $(10!/(3!4!3!))* (x)^3(2y)^4(3)^3$

Answer (score 2):

The terms of the development will be of the form $$\frac{10!}{i!j!k!}x^i(2y)^j3^k \quad\text{ with } \ i+j+k=10$$

With $i=3$ and $j=4$ this leaves $k=3$. So it's 
$$\frac{10!}{3!4!3!}x^3(2y)^43^3$$
which means the coefficient of $x^3y^4$  is equal to 
$$\frac{10!}{3!4!3!}2^4\cdot 3^3$$

---

(Compilation of comments by  [Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040119/multinomial-theorem-find-the-coefficient-of-x3-y4-in-x2y310#comment2119562_1040119) and [Hanne](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040119/multinomial-theorem-find-the-coefficient-of-x3-y4-in-x2y310#comment2119616_1040119).)